# Sharepoint 2013 eLerning

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Do you know any eLerning extension for Sharepoint?

Could you give me name for them. How much they cost? Do you know any free one which will work with SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 2):

I did a Google search for "elearning sharepoint" and came up with several hits. Here is one example: http://www.sharepointlms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little confusing?
What you want, creating an eLearning site in SharePoint or looking for eLearning resources /training?

for eLearning Site In SharePoint, i can couple of choices

- Free from Codeplex, [SharePoint Learning Kit](http://slk.codeplex.com/), Supports both 2010 & 2013,
- another Option is LMS, http://www.elearningforce.com/Pages/SharePoint-LMS.aspx

But if you are looking for the SharePoint course online, then their are many available as other fellow mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Pluralsight has nice online tutorials as well, however these are subscription based.

Comment: And this is a e-learning Extension ?

Comment: here are few of the SP13 tutorials http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Find?highlight=true&searchTerm=sharepoint+2013 
Please visit the site for more details

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this, there are some labs, where you can 
practise.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123606.aspx

Comment: But I must find aut eLearning portal to inplement on Sharepoint 2013 not a learning me.

Comment: Have you really taken a look at it?

Comment: Yes I look there and I don't see anything about eLearning on main site.